# How make \vline fit to the content?

Tags: tables

I to make my \vline adjust dynamically to the content as this increase or decrease your height. Is it possible?

Ps.: The solution I think is make the tabular environment increase your length naturally, it would be perfect.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X}
         01/2019 - 12/2023 & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t][15cm]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}\\%
         Employer & \\%
         Job title & \\[28ex]
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: Result I get, but wish auto, fit \vline to content]

Comment: if you did not use multirow and did not force the height with `[28ex]` a `|` column cell would extend to the natural height. You are not allowing tabularx to work at all here as the only thing in the `X` column is a fixed width parbox, so tabularx can not usefully adjust the size of the X column at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I do it, my right side description fit only into the first row, creating a gap between Employer and Job title

Comment: see egreg's answer for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `\multirow`, but rather keep in a single cell the text in the left column, which is done here with a nested `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\job}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l|X@{}}
\job{01/2019 - 12/2023 \\ Employer \\ Job title} &
\lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, because `\vrule` TeX primitive is able to set its height and depth to the height and depth of the surrounding box.

An example which uses only TeX primitives are here:

```
\hbox{\bf WORK EXPERIENCES}
\medskip\hrule

\hbox to\hsize{\def\\{\hfil\break}\parindent=0pt
   \hss
   \vtop{\hsize=.2\hsize \medskip
      01/2019--12/2023 \\
      Emloyer \\
      Job Title
   }
   \hss\vrule\hss
   \vtop{\hsize=.7\hsize \medskip
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
      vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
      gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
      vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
      morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
   }
}
```

If you want to know how it works then you can study the features of the TeX primitives `\hbox`, `\vtop`, `\hss`, `\hsize`, `\parindent`, `\hrule`, `\vrule`.

Comment: it works, but is TeX is so hard for a newbie

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. TeX seems much simpler to me than LaTeX.

Comment: Could you tell me some way to learn TeX? Because I feel is so hard to find TeX tutorial

Comment: For example TeX in a Nutshell, http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf